# modify the underlying struct for a provided interface Golang where the underlying struct is not exported

Tags: go, pointers, interface

I have a scenario I have to write a method where I modify the passed interface's underlying struct, I have realized that I can pass a pointer to the interface and then use the pointer to get the underlying struct and manipulate it, but from what I have learnt using pointers to interface is almost never required. Can anyone suggest any better way to achieve the required functionality below?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

type iperson interface {
    walk()
    changeName(string) *person
}

func (p person) walk() {

    fmt.Println("tip tap toe")
}

func (p person) changeName(name string) *person {

    return &person{name: name, age: p.age}
}

func modifyStr(s *string) {

    *s = "world"

}

func modifyStruct(p *person) {

    *p = person{name: "john", age: 10}

}

func modifyInterface(i iperson) {

    //i.walk()
    p := i.(*person)
    *p = person{name: "diff name", age: 111}

}

func modifyInterfaceWithUnexportedStruct(target interface{}) {

    // We can do so by type assertion on pointer to interface but this is not recommended
    // this works but is there any other way possible? i.e without having access to underlying struct but still manipulating it?

    p := target.(*iperson)
    *p = *(*p).changeName("some random name")

}

func main() {

    //modifying a string in a function call

    a := "hello"
    modifyStr(&a)
    fmt.Println(a)

    //modify a struct in a function call

    b := person{name: "sam", age: 2}
    modifyStruct(&b)
    fmt.Println(b)

    //modify a interface in a function call using the underlying struct

    c := person{name: "tom", age: 2}
    modifyInterface(&c)
    fmt.Println(c)

    //modify a passed interface in a function call without using the underlying struct

    d := iperson(person{name: "abc", age: 21})
    fmt.Println(d)
    modifyInterfaceWithUnexportedStruct(&d)
    fmt.Println(d)

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by private? Do you mean unexported? If so then you can NOT modify such a struct outside of the package in which it is declared. If you want to modify it only within its own package then what you mean by "private", and how it relates to your question, becomes even less clear.

Comment: This question could use clarification... Whether or not it's exported, you cannot modify a struct outside the package in which it is defined. A pointer to an interface is almost never correct or necessary. You cannot manipulate an underlying struct without type assertion, and if you think you need to modify an underlying struct, that indicates a significant design issue: if you're using interfaces correctly, you generally shouldn't need access to the underlying struct.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I mean unexported. 
No I do not want to modify in within its own package.

Comment: @Adrian I understand, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface already provides a `changeName` method,  but it's implementation does not change the receiving `person`'s name,  it returns a new `person` with the same age as the receiver and the passed name.

The idea of an interface is that the code that interacts with the interface doesn't need to know the particular of the implementation.   But if `changeName` returns a `*person` you're already forcing the caller to know implementation details.

So why not implement change Name like this ?

```
func (p *person) changeName(n string) {
  p.name = n
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your response, actually I do not control the implementation of `changeName` in my case, but the implementation of this external library that I am using returns a new person with the same age as a receiver and the passed name.